# Efficient way to solve (A & N) + (B & N) + (C & N)

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

What will be the efficient way to solve 
`(A & N) + (B & N) + (C & N) ..` and so on.
where `&` stands for bit wise AND operation.
and `A` , `B` , `C` , `N` are all positive integers.
Is it possible to reduce the computation.

Comment: I don't think there's a way. But I highly doubt that the extra `&` would have a non-negligible impact in any practical case.

Comment: There might be an optimization for specific values of N (for N = 0, the answer is always 0, for example; if the least significant bits of N are all 1 bits for more bits than the largest value in A, B, C, then the answer is simply A+B+C).  But for general values of N, there isn't a short way to do it.

Comment: @ugoren the problem mentioned above is a subset of a large problem where AND operation has to be done 10^6 * 10^6 times..ans Hence the time matters.

Comment: @MahavirChopra, If you do something simple 10^12 times, it's very likely that getting all this data from memory is going to be your worst problem. You can try to omit the `&` (and get a wrong result) just to see if it makes a difference.

Answer (score 1):

If you are combining bit masks then you may get what you need with: `(A & N) | (B & N) |...`  in that case you will do better with (A|B|C|...) & N.

**N.B.** if `N = 0x0020` and `A = 0x003f`, `B=0x0a25` then:

```
(A & N) + (B & N) = 0x0040
```

but

```
(A|B)&N = 0x0020
```

which is more often what is needed when combining bit fields.

Comment: Depends on whether or not he is worried about the carry bits

Comment: Agreed - hence the qualifier - the most usual reason to do something like this is to combine filtered bit masks which the original code would fail for due to carries, _some of the time_.

Comment: Steve I am not trying to do the OR instead i am trying the addition operation, But seems there is is no easy way possible.

Comment: Why do you need the & operation?

Comment: Well this is a c code and i have been asked to `and` all the values of a array pair wise.

Comment: Which is _not_ what your code above is doing you are calculating the sum of a lot of separate values after they have each been `and`ed with a constant value.

Comment: @MahavirChopra Can you give a bit more context? Is it a sort of school/college assignment or there is a real programming problem behind. In this latter case can you explain what you are actually trying to solve?

Comment: @SteveBarnes It is, It is actually a sub problem of my original one in the sense that, I take one value and `AND` with all rest and similarly proceed n times.This is a inner loop of my actual code.

Comment: @LorenzoDonati What i actually wanna do is take all the values of array. And find the sum of all the pair wise `AND` combination.
for ex:
repeat(i,n)
    repeat(j,n)
        sum += a[i] & a[j];
Now what i actually asked here is just the optimization of my inner loop!

Comment: That is a _VERY_ different question.

Answer (score 1):

No, it won't work. You always have the danger that an addition in the masked-out area will mess up your data.

E.g., if `N = 0x0020, A = 0x001f, B=0x002f` or `N = 0b0100000, A = 0b0011111, B = 0b0101111`

Here the addition will bring you

```
  0b0011111
+ 0b0101111
-----------
  0b1001110
& 0b0100000
-----------
  0b0000000
===========
```

Here, the addition of the lower 5 bis has an impact on bit 5.

If you do the `& N` before the addition, you will have no such impact:

```
  0b0000000
+ 0b0100000
-----------
  0b0100000
===========
```

Comment: IT turns out it cant be reduced and i ill have to proceed with long computations right?

Answer (score 0):

As shown by the other answers, that does not work in general. In fact, it usually doesn't.

Not to advertise my own stuff here, but [this site](http://haroldbot.cloudapp.net) can solve such a thing. For example if you enter

```
solve[n] (a & n) + (b & n) == (a + b) & n
```

Which means "solve for n such that for every a, b, `(a & n) + (b & n) == (a + b) & n`"

In other words, find that `n` which makes it work for all `a`'s and `b`'s.

There are only two results. -1, and 0. It makes sense that it works for those: if `n = -1`, then there's just no masking at all, and if `n = 0`, clearly the result is zero either way.

But it doesn't work for anything else, unless you have some specific guarantees about the `a`'s and `b`'s.

Comment: Your calculation misses the other cases: where N is any power of 2 - 1, the & becomes mod N+1, and the mode can be moved outside.

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker I originally thought so, that's why I tested it. But it's actually not so: consider the case where A, B and N are all 3, for example.